# Angular 2 performance problems

Tags: javascript, performance, angular

I'm developing a project in Angular 4, but it has big performance problems to the point that when I write in an input it lasts 10 secs assigning the value to it, I've read about and it seems to be due Change Detection. A solution I found was turning all components up on  ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush so change detector doesn't trigger as much as before. However performance hasn't improved.

I did a console.log into AfterViewChecked() lifecycle hook of one of the components but it triggers too many times, doing actions that has nothing to do with though (which makes me think component's change detector is triggering all this times). The weirddest part is that I did same in other component but it doesn't trigger that much (I guess it's the right behavior).

I don't know how many components has this problem. How can I solve it please?

Comment: I assume you bind to methods like `[someProp]="getSomeValue()"` in one or more of your components template. Perhaps some event bindings where the events happen too frequently, or to complex code in event handlers, that doesn't complete before the next event.

Comment: otherwise there is no way of telling what could cause your performance issues whit the information you provided. Try to reproduce in a plunker.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Comment: PS: Your title reads Angular 2, your text says Angular 4, your tag Angular... You should remedy this and be consistent. Angular is too generic and can mean AngularJS too..

Comment: @JGFMK No, Angular cannot mean AngularJS. Angular means Angular, and AngularJS means AngularJS. The tag "angular" is for Angular, and the tag "angularjs" is for AngularJS, so this question is tagged properly See http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/branding-guidelines-for-angular-and.html.

Comment: thx for clarification

Comment: If you check out my answer again, you'll see I updated it with info on ngRx.

Answer (score 0):

If it's relevant to you, have you already tried using [*ngFor trackBy](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/)?

I think you also might want to take a look at ngRx then. There's a good video on [Youtube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=cyaAhXHhxgk) about it. Here's their [sample project](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ngFor trackBy, but did not solve this problem

Comment: I suppose you've seen this too? https://medium.com/@areai51/the-4-stages-of-perf-tuning-for-your-angular2-app-922ce5c1b294 and this.. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist